# Add GCC options to top of C source file

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-options

Is is possible to put something at the top of the C source file, like

```
// GCC_OPTIONS=-g,-Wall
```

that will add those options automatically to gcc every time you compile this file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes it is, at least for some flags. You can push and pop [diagnostic settings](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html) like this:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-pedantic"
#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wall"
```

This is also possible for [optimization levels on a per-function level](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas.html#Function-Specific-Option-Pragmas):

```
#pragma GCC optimize ("string"...)
```

These `#pragma` definitions affect all code after them in a source file.

See these other questions for more information:

- [Switching off optimization for a specific function in gcc 4.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395145/switching-off-optimization-for-a-specific-function-in-gcc-4-2-2)
- [Selectively disable GCC warnings for only part of a translation unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965093/selectively-disable-gcc-warnings-for-only-part-of-a-translation-unit/3394305#3394305)

Comment: Neither of these are equivalent to the options he's asking about.

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen These settings affect all functions defined later in a source file, so to some extent they can be equivalent: put them on the top and they kind of become global.

Comment: No debug unfortunately it seems: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2006821/is-there-a-gcc-pragma-to-override-generation-of-debug-info-g-for-some-section

Comment: Is there a pragma for setting an -f/-fno flag (e.g., ` -fno-ipa-icf`)?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Some compiler options have `#define` equivalents, but not those.  This belongs in your make file (or equivalent).  With GNU Make:

```
CFLAGS += -g -Wall
```

Comment: `-Wall` has an in source equivalent.

Comment: @Matt, what is it?  Your answer doesn't give one, and `#pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wall"` definitely doesn't work in GCC 4.4.