# Is it possible to pass the compiler an option from the program?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, c-preprocessor

I would like to pass certain options to the compiler such as `-Wall`. The IDE I am working in makes it difficult to change the flags repeatedly, hence I would like to pass the compiler option from within the source file itself.

Is this possible via a preprocessor directive or a hack of some sort (restricted to the source code to be compiled)?

For example, say I want to compile a program with the `-Wall` and I do not have access to the arguments being passed to gcc from the IDE. I would like to do something like `#<directive> WALL` that the preprocessor looks for and enables for the compilation process.

Comment: I think there is a similar question already... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3731885/add-gcc-options-to-top-of-c-source-file

Comment: Do you not have access to a makefile? Especially on Linux, that's the typical place to control compiler options.